# Cannot see selected files info toast after updating

Tags: pantheon-files

I have 2 laptops running Elementary Juno.

On one laptop, I have all the latest updates. When I select a few files/folders and hover over them, I cannot see a toast message which says how many items are selected and what is their size.

On the other laptop with is not updated, I can see the toast.

Please let me know if there is a way to get the toast back.

Comment: I have the latest updates and everything is fine with those messages. Try to reboot your computer and check again to see if the problem you have is just temporary.

Comment: The number of selected items is only showing in Icon View for me.  The info overlay is intentionally suppressed in List View to avoid obscuring information I suppose. In Column View it should work but there seems to be a regression - it is only showing info for the hovered file even if several are selected.  Not sure when that started happening,

Comment: @JeremyWootten I was using list view. I can confirm that I can see the toast in the icon view. It would be great to see that in the list view as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do to get the overlay in List view at the moment - you need to switch to Icon View.  I have raise this issue: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1060